# Download data from DropBox to remote server (via scp)

Tags: linux, scp, file-transfer, dropbox

I'm trying to transfer some large, gzipped files from a collaborator's DropBox to a remote server. Is there a way to do this with `scp`? Or is there a preferred method?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a headless Dropbox client. Headless means it can be installed on a server and doesn't require a GUI. Below are the instructions from [their website](https://www.dropbox.com/install)

> Dropbox Headless Install via command line
>
> The Dropbox daemon works fine on all 32-bit and 64-bit Linux servers. To install, run the following command in your Linux terminal.

```
32-bit:

cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -

64-bit:

cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

> Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

> If you're running Dropbox on your server for the first time, you'll be asked to copy and paste a link in a working browser to create a new account or add your server to an existing account. Once you do, your Dropbox folder will be created in your home directory. Download this Python script to control Dropbox from the command line. For easy access, put a symlink to the script anywhere in your PATH.

Realized there's a link in the last paragraph to a python script to help you control Dropbox. You'll want to do this after you install the client:

```
sudo wget https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py -O /usr/local/bin/dropbox.py
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dropbox.py
```

With that you should be able to control the Dropbox client just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rclone, configuring two storage backend:

> sftp: https://rclone.org/sftp/

and

> Dropbox: https://rclone.org/dropbox/

then you can copy the files with something like this:

```
rclone copy dropbox_store:/file.gz sftp_store:/file.gz
```

*Note that you will use your bandwidth for downloading and uploading the files.*